# accessing apache from another computer using http://hostname works but http://ipaddress gives 403 forbidden

Tags: http-status-code-403, apache2.4, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL running on windows 10 with Apache Version 2.4.7 (Ubuntu) [IP: 192.168.1.10] and I get a 403 forbidden error when accessing from IP: 192.168.1.107 using http://192.168.1.10, however, http://mmtserver works.  When I ping mmtserver from .107 it gives me replies from fe80::65a5:53a6:cf99:5644%6  [Maybe an IPv6 issue?].  I've tried several  changes regarding allow,deny and allow from all, but keep coming up with the 403s.  I've googled and searched for similar stackoverflow 403 issues, but can't seem to find a solution that works for me.  Any suggestions?

Here are some relevant excerpts from /etc/hosts, /etc/apache2/apache.conf, /etc/apache2/enabled-sites/000-default.conf, and /etc/apache2/ports.conf.

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.1.10    mmtserver
```

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
ServerName 192.168.1.10:80
<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 192.168.1.10:80
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.10:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
  ServerName 192.168.1.10:80

        <Directory />
                Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/var/log/apache2/error_log

```
[Thu Mar 15 08:01:14.560826 2018] [:error] [pid 848] [client 192.168.1.107] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "^[\\\\d.:]+$" at REQUEST_HEADERS:Host. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"] [line "98"] [id "960017"] [rev "2"] [msg "Host header is a numeric IP address"] [data "192.168.1.10"] [severity "WARNING"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.8"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/IP_HOST"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-21"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A7"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [tag "http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.01.hackerbasher.aspx"] [hostname "192.168.1.10"] [uri "/favicon.ico"] [unique_id "Wqpumn8AAQEAAANQZyMAAAAA"]
```

Commented out line 98 in /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf

```
#SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "^[\d.:]+$" "phase:2,rev:'2',ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.8',maturity:'9',accuracy:'9',t:none,block,msg:'Host header is a numeric IP address',logdata:'%{matched_var}',severity:'4',id:'960017',tag:'OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/IP_HOST',tag:'WASCTC/WASC-21',tag:'OWASP_TOP_10/A7',tag:'PCI/6.5.10',tag:'http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2005.01.hackerbasher.aspx',setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.warning_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/POLICY/IP_HOST-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}"
```

restarted apache2 and http://ipaddress works now